# Can I install a whole house water filter that has 1” fittings with a 3/4 supply coming from the house main?

Tags: plumbing

I am installing a whole house filter and the connections are all 1 inch. My incoming main (city) is also 1 inch, but has been reduced to 3/4. Can I flip a reducer around and go from 3/4 to 1” pipe or do I need to convert the whole line to 1” from the meter?

Comment: Could you install the filter closer to the main? With a 1" main, I'm inclined to put a Tee to send 3/4" directly to the water heater and 3/4" to cold water when reducing pipe size, rather than forcing everything through one 3/4" pipe and losing the benefit of the 1" feed.

Answer (score 1):

3/4 inch to 1 inch bushings installed in the filter will work just fine.

My better half was GM of an international filter manufacturer for 30 years. She advised the reducer bushing is the industry standard for 3/4 to 1 inch applications.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have any choice, really.
Performance characteristics are going to change with the installation of a restriction (whole-house water filters are a restriction) in the supply line. You are creating a restriction, whether or not you use adapters to hook it up. The type of filter assembly and media, the supply line arrangement, the setup downstream of the filter, and how the system will be used will all affect final performance.

So, you certainly can use bushings/reducers to hook it up. Know that you may be using less than the filter's max capacity, and also know that *residence time* is part of how filters/purifiers accomplish their task, and flow reduction is a normal result of their use.